# Let a and b be natural numbers such that $2a - b, a - 2b$ and $a + b$ are all distinct squares. What is the smallest possible value of $b$?

Tags: square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Let a and b be natural numbers such that $2a - b, a - 2b$ and $a + b$ are all distinct squares.
What is the smallest possible value of $b$?

Let, $2a-b=k^2, a-2b=p^2, a+b=q^2$.

$k^2=p^2+q^2$ after adding any of the two equations.

How to proceed further?

Comment: Differences of squares are more interesting because they can be factored.  Alternately, you could just try some of the small Pythagorean triangles you know and see if they work.

Comment: $k^2 + p^2 = 3(a-b)$ which *might* be interesting.  Or might not.  $(k^2+p^2)q^2 = 3(a^2 - b^2)$.  Interesting looking but might not pan out to much.  But *definitely* follow Ross Millikan's advice and note $(k-p)(k+p)=k^2 -p^2 = a+b = q^2$

Answer (score 5):

If you subtract the last two you get $q^2-p^2=3b$.  If you add the first and last you get $k^2+q^2=3a$.  No primitive Pythagorean triangle has legs that differ by a multiple of $3$, so we need a triangle that has a common factor of $3$.  The smallest such is $9-12-15$ and we find
$$3b=144-81=63\\b=21\\3a=225+144=369\\a=123$$
This is the smallest $b$ because the difference of the two legs must be at least $3$.  If the shorter leg is $c$ we have $(c+3)^2-c^2=6c+9$ and $b$ will grow with the shorter leg.

Comment: That was a good observation about how no primitive triple legs differ by $3.\quad$ In fact, they can only differ by $p^n$, where $p$ is prime and $\quad p\equiv\pm1\mod 8\quad$ and $n\in\{0,\mathbb{N}\}.\\$ 

$\text{Under}\space100,\space p\in\big\{1,7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97\big\}$

Answer (score 0):

The first few quintuples are
$$(a,b,a+b,2a-b,a-2b)\\\in\big\{
(6,3,9,9,0 ),\quad 
(24,12,36,36,0 ),\quad 
(54,27,81,81,0 ),\quad 
(96,48,144,144,0 ),\\ 
\mathbf{(123,21,144,225,81 )},\quad 
(150,75,225,225,0 ),\quad 
(216,108,324,324,0 ),\\ 
(294,147,441,441,0 ),\quad 
(384,192,576,576,0 ),\quad 
(486,243,729,729,0 ),\\ 
\mathbf{(492,84,576,900,324 )},\quad 
(600,300,900,900,0 ),\quad 
(726,363,1089,1089,0 ),\\ 
(864,432,1296,1296,0 ),\quad 
\mathbf{(939,357,1296,1521,225 )},\quad  \cdots\big\}
$$
The lowest value of $\space b\space $ that works is either $\space 3\space $ or $\space 21\space $ depending on whether or not you allow $\space (a-2b)=0\space $.